# What term should I use to refer to an entrepreneur I invested in?

Tags: investing, terminology

I am planning to invest in a project of another entrepreneur. How would I refer to this person? Is there a term which describes my relationship to them?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place for this.

Comment: "Asset" or "Liability" depending on how good the person is. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't go wrong with referring to him as Mr. Doe. If you know this person on a personal level, you could probably refer to him as John, although I would stick with Mr. Doe until he invites you to call him John. Personally, I think an air of formality is warranted when a person is caring for some of your money.

As for a term to describe your relationship with this person, I would say you have a variety of options. You said this person was "another entrepreneur" in your question. This implies that you're an entrepreneur. In that case, colleague or fellow entrepreneur might be acceptable. You might refer to him as the CEO or founder or something else of the company you've invested in.

Comment: Side note: if his name isn't John Doe, it probably wouldn't work to call him Mr. Doe or John.